# How to send CGRect Value from titanium to ios-module

Tags: ios, titanium, titanium-modules

I need to set CGRect in iOS-module which receives its value from titanium. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

In titanium use this:

```
module.setRect({
     x:10,
     y:10,
     width:100,
     height:100
});
```

And in IOS Module:

```
-(void)setRect:(id)value{
   CGRect rect = [TiUtils rectValue:value];
}
```